# How to upload a model file to solr

Tags: solr

I'm trying to upload the most simple model to solr 7.3.1 and I get an error.

Model

```
{ 
   "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.model.MultipleAdditiveTreesModel", 
   "name" : "my", 
   "features":[], 
   "params" : { 
       "trees" : [ 
           { 
               "weight" : 1, 
               "root" : { 
                   "value" : -10 
               }} ]}}
```

Error

```
     "error":{ 
        "metadata":[ 
            "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException", 
            "root-error-class","java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"], 
        "msg":"org.apache.solr.ltr.model.ModelException: Model type does not exist org.apache.solr.ltr.model.MultipleAdditiveTreesModel", 
        "code":400}}
```

I inserted the configurations to solrconfig.xml like :

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

and started solr using   `-Dsolr.ltr.enabled=true`

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: kindly provide the error you are getting in the questions so as people can support you in better way

Comment: It is provided in the Error section